# SpringDataCassandra (SDC) : Creation Queries don't return the POJO inserted

Tags: spring-data, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

I've written a Repository that extends the CassandsraRepository. Unlike SQLs Spring Data Repository functions, SDC doesn't return the POJO of the record inserted. So for example, I insert an user_id and name, the repository function will not return the Obj("ID","Name"). Is this somehting specific to Cassandra or am I missing something ?

I am using SDC version 1.5.0RC1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the insert() method from the CassandraTemplate that is correct is will not return the persisted entity, but the entity you passed to the insert method.

According to the API if you use the CassandraRepository save() method you will be returned the actual persisted entity

```
save
<S extends T> S save(S entity)
Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.
Parameters:
entity -
Returns:
the saved entity
```